# Access the "Locale" for Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How can I access the "Locale" set in `File > Spreadsheet Settings > Locale`?

`Session.getActiveUserLocale()` does not match the value chosen in `File > Spreadsheet Settings > Locale`.

**- Extra Info -**

**Reproduce:** In Spreadsheet Settings, you can choose "Italy" for your Locale.  `Session.getActiveUserLocale()` will return "en" instead of "it".

**My use case:** I am trying to know when a function should be written with ";" or "," separating its parameters.  Google Sheets switches to ";" or "," automatically when `File > Spreadsheet Settings > Locale` is changed. So I want to know what property it is watching to make this change.

Comment: Can you please explain how you determine a "separator" if you know spreadsheet locale? Is there a gas function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the Session method will get the locale associated with the Google Apps Script. To get the locale of the spreadsheet itself, use the Spreadsheet [getSpreadsheetLocale() method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getSpreadsheetLocale()).