# Auto translation with GOOGLETRANSLATE is not working

Tags: google-sheets

The issue is simple, when I try to do auto translate from English to a detected language I got an error, the formula is:

```
=GOOGLETRANSLATE("Cat"; "en"; "auto")
```

and the error is something like

```
Error, Google Translate does not support translation from en to pl-PL.
```

The problem (I think) is that `GOOGLETRANSLATE` is supposed to get language as two letter code when default value is language + country code (which is not supported https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093331?hl=en)

Is it possible to fix that? I would like to translate to user's language (so I want to use "auto" value), no matter what is the language and I assume that if the problem occurs for one language it will happen for different one.

Comment: This is not an issue, I want auto-translation to users language, even if I use it like this `=GOOGLETRANSLATE("Cat";"en";"auto")` I got the same error message, `auto` suppose to be converted to local language which, in case of Google Spreadsheet, is "pl-PL" (in my case), which is wrong because this language format is not supported.

Manual language support works but what if I want share something with users from a lot of other countries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue for Russian. The formula `=GOOGLETRANSLATE("Cat"; "en"; "auto")` gives the error:

> Google Translate does not support translating from en to ru-RU.

This is Google issue, the best way is to report it:

- Menu: Help > Report a problem

Here's a workaround:

- make a script to [detect sheet's locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386063/access-the-locale-for-google-sheets).
- use [regex](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_regexp.asp) to extract first part of a locale string.

Here's the sample code:

```
function getLocale()
{
  var locale = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetLocale(); // pl_PL    
  return /(.*)_/.exec(locale)[1]; // pl
}
```

The usage:

`=GOOGLETRANSLATE("Cat"; "en"; getLocale())`

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried to use `;` instead of `,`.

Example:

```
=GOOGLETRANSLATE(A1 ; "auto"; "bg")
```

Comment: I'm not sure why did this answer get more upvotes, in the original question I posted a formula with `;`

Comment: Because, usually the formulas are using comas (,) like the SUM formula for example. But this formula uses semicolon (;) and most of the time we are trying the first way. I searched long time after I found why it is.

Answer (score 1):

auto-translate is supported only for these 16 locales:

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| brazil | germany | mexico | spain |
| canada (english) | hong kong | philippines | taiwan |
| china | italy | portugal | united kingdom |
| france | japan | south korea | united states |

see more at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73767720/5632629